# Replace arg0,arg1,... with meaningful names and javadocs for SDKs that don't have them?

Tags: java, function, parameters, javadoc

Many times SDKs are missing meaningful names for their functions' parameters and descriptions of what they do.

This happens even on popular SDKs, including Java SDK and Android SDK.

I wish to change it so that instead of remembering what each argument says (and what each function does), we would actually see it and have it being auto-completed .

Again , I wish to add missing javadocs data, even if there are already javadocs for the SDK . I wish to add my own Javadocs, to fill the gaps that the developer has forgot to add.

Is it possible? If so, how ?

Comment: *"we would actually see it"*  See what exactly?  The code of the method?  It is not in the compiled Jar.  Decompilation of the method might help, but it won't produce nicely formatted Java source.

Comment: @PaulBellora i meant the cases that we don't have javadocs, as the SDK doesn't have them, or that they miss some descriptions...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Eclipse helps a lot with the auto-completion, plus it puts the real names of the parameters instead of just "arg0,arg1,...".

Comment: You could always write your own and attach them... but then you have to maintain them.

Comment: @PaulBellora this is not relevant . i already know why it occurs. i want to add my own "patches" to the javadocs , whether it exists (with partial entries) or not.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How do I do that without editing HTML ? is there an automatic tool for that?

Comment: Extract your method signatures (e.g. open the class in eclipse); then write a skeleton of the java with the javadocs...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm not aware of one...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch all i know that if i'm the maker of the sdk, eclipse can do it for me (assuming that i've written some javadocs in the code itself). what do you mean by extracting the method signatures? i wish to do it for all classes and their methods. how do it even list them all?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I do know that I can at least see the functions using a tool like this : http://jd.benow.ca/ , but I can't understand how to add javadocs that I create to a third party library...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Close vote retracted. But maybe you could edit the question to make it more clear that you want to add your own javadocs.

Comment: @PaulBellora ok i've updated the question. please tell me if it's now better.